# Invite Friends lead them to a blank page

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, invite

I implemented a FB Invite your Friends Button on one of my Facebook Apps. - the invite works well - the invited user gets the right message but when he clicks on it - it just lead to nowhere (a blank page).

How can I direct where this invite should lead to ?

Here is my invite code :

```
function invitefriends() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',message: 'Einladen',data: '128', title: 'Lade Deine Freunde ein'}, requestCallback);
}
function requestCallback(response) {
//
}
```

Sorry - I searched already for a long time via google etc. but nothing solved my problem :(

---

edit
I found the problem - but now another problem occured.
The problem was that my index.php on my CANVAS URL was blank and only my tab.php (PAGE TAB URL) was the content. But since I am using a LIKE Gate (where people have to LIKE my page before they can use the app) - the invite leads always to the PLEASE LIKE site :/

is there still any chance I can choose where the invite should lead ?

Comment: Do you have a canvas page for your app?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not change where the invite sends the users.  You can however have a simple redirect on your canvas page -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  top.location.href = "YOUR_TAB_PAGE_URL";
</script>
```

Comment: No problem @kri! Happy to help! The [best way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) to say thanks here is to vote on and/or [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) answers that you found helpful.